# How long to boot on El Capitan

Tags: macos, startup, benchmark

I have a mac mini (Late 2012) 2,3 GHz Intel Core i7, 8 Go 1333 MHz DDR3 with bluetooth keyboard and trackpad.

Since I upgraded to El Capitan many tasks are incredibly slower than before.
For example, the boot time before I get the login prompt is 80 seconds.

Then, once I entered the password it takes 90 additional seconds before the Finder is stable (without the colored wheel popping on and off)

Then when I click on Safari, it takes Safari 23 seconds before I can actually type in the address bar. Note that after that even if I quit Safari, it will restart in a second. So I'm measuring here the first start after boot.

Total: That's more than 3 minutes before I crawl the web which takes me back to the first imac with macOS 9 ages. (Joke: Was it a preliminary information that macOS days are coming back?)

Seriously, I wonder if it's related to my machine or to El Capitan.
Could you answer how long are these timings in your configuration so that I can compare?

Comment: It's most likely the old HD. I'd recommend you get an SSD.

Comment: Asking like that (especially better benchmark results will be frustrating for you) won't help you with your potential problem. Better add error messages or log entries. Or share an [etrecheck](https://etrecheck.com/) report. BTW: Early 2011 MBP 2.7 i7, 4 GB, 500 GB non-Apple SSD: 17 sec > login prompt; 10 seconds with some login times > Finder; 1 second Safari > apple.stackexchange.com.